# How to unpause activated autoplay?

Tags: youtube

For like 1 week I'm now not getting any autoplay progress anymore.
Whenever a song ends it shows the next song and the circle for playing it immediately appears in the centre, but the filling circle that indicates when it will start playing the next song just aborts at, like 20%, gives a short notification about "autoplay paused", and just begins again. So while the slider for autoplay is active it just says it's active but paused in the screen. How to fix/unpause this?

Comment: I'm having this problem too, and this is the only search result for my query. Let me know when you get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

On the video you are watching click on "settings" then turn off autoplay and turn it back on. This fixed it for me. Don't use the autoplay option next to "Up Next"; this will not fix it (for me).

Answer (score -1):

just put Linux on a Thumbdrive and boot it. If, like me, you want to watch YouTube when you go to sleep and wake up to find it paused it don't do this in Linux.